# Is beef 'aged' in vacuum packed bags?

Tags: beef

I got some beef this weekend with the following label. This label is obviously not aimed at the consumer, but as I was after a single piece, the guy behind the counter gave it to me in its original packaging.  When I got home I noticed the details of the label which opens a whole raft of questions:

- I'm guessing USE AFTER instruction is to ensure the meat is sufficiently mature before being sold, is that correct?
- If that's true, is the whole aging process done in these vacuum-pack bags?
- If so, could I have kept it for a further 19 days before opening (I bought it on the 5th)  for a more mature beef?  Who needs "Jamie Oliver Matured for 21 days" if we can just do it ourselves?

**PURCHASED:  5th,  USE BY (on sale label): 6th**

[image: Beef Packaging Label]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, vacuum sealed beef is 'wet aged,' which produces a cheaper though inferior product to dry aging.

You can age yourself at home, you just need decent climate control, and the knowledge to know the difference between good aging and bad critters infesting your meat.Bear in mind also that there is significant loss in dry aging, as you have to cut off the outside of the meat.